# Interpreting a fictitious line interval (metric) with 3 extra dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, general-relativity

Consider a fictitious line interval (metric) with 3 extra dimensions as follows:

$ds^2 = -2dt^2 + a^2(t) \left( \frac{dr^2}{1 - r^2} + r^2 d\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta d\phi^2 \right) + da_{1}^2+da_{2}^2+da_{3}^2 $

Let's put the condition that $da_{1}^2+da_{2}^2+da_{3}^2 = dt^2$

How can we interpret such a metric, geometrically?

Is this metric and the geometry equivalent to the usual metric and geometry in the 4-dim spacetime given that it always cancels out the 2 factor in the timelike component of the metric, unless the timelike condition on the distance in the extra dimensions is released?

Comment: I do not think that this describes an $S^3$ object that moves with the speed of light. Whatever those three extra coordinates are. The constraint $dt^2=da_1^2+da_2^2+da_3^2$ makes them gratuitous and we have the well-known FLRW metric that describes a spherically symmetric expanding universe. Without the constraint you have a 7-dimensional universe that expands in its first three spacial dimensions. In a hyper dimensional sense it is a cylindrically symmetric universe. Where does that question come from?

Comment: From nowhere, just a thought experiment to make sense of geometric objects in extra dimensions

Comment: Metrics don't model objects. They model lengths between points and angles between vectors.  A more interesting variant I think would be a truly cylindrically symmetric version of the 4-dimensional FLRW space time. You could compare its curvature tensors with what we know and think about an interpretation.

Comment: Actually, my questions is how can I write the math to describe a 3-sphere, embedded in higher, 6-dim space and moves along a chosen direction, path between points, in that 3 extra dimensions a1, a2, a3, with zero distance in the x, y, z dimension?

Comment: This too is very unspecific. A $3$-sphere is obviously characterized by its center. What metric does the space have that it moves in? Please refrain from throwing around thought experiments. Give them some thoughts before posting.

Comment: I think you just provided the answer, the center is missing here, any resource recommendations for better understanding of extra dimensions geometries?

Comment: Not really. Imho 4d has enough interesting extra dimensions. Yesterday I compared a bit the classic spherically symmetric FLRW space time and the one we get by making it cylindrically symmetric: $$
ds^2=-dt+a^2(t)\textstyle\Big(\frac{d\rho^2}{1-\rho^2}+\rho^2\,d\theta\Big)+\color{red}{dz^2}\,,\quad \rho^2=x^2+y^2\,.
$$
I highly recommend to calculate its Ricci tensor and ponder about what that means. There is not always a resource for everything. It is more exciting to find out things ourselves.

Comment: calculate its Ricci tensor, this is very helpful, thanks, I got my answer.

Comment: Any advanced differential-geometry textbook will cover the subject without regard to dimension.

Comment: My question was actually that if the two metrics are fully equivalent with the timelike condition suggested, but it seems that Ricci tensor will be different despite the condition,right?

Comment: That "timelike" condition is strictly speaking a *lightlike* condition. To find out what it means make your life simple. The metric $$
ds^2=-2dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2
$$
is Lorentzian with speed of light $\sqrt{2}\,.$ The constraint
$dt^2=dz^2$ turns it into the degenerate metric
$$
ds^2=-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2
$$
in which objects that extend only in the $z$-direction have length zero. Physically this means that any object that moves in the $z$-direction moves at the speed $c=1\,.$

Comment: Excellent insight, a good answer to my question, already.

Comment: But wasn't this my original question too? That if any object moves in the a1,a2,a3 directions it moves at the speed 1? I'm confused again!

Comment: You are confused because you do not even seem to remember your own words: "Can we say that it describes an expanding $S^3$ object (low dim universe) moving with the speed of light in a 7-dim spacetime (high dim universe)?" This is now buried in half a dozen edits of the question. *An* object is not *any* object. Clarity, wording, clarity, wording, ... Please get into the rabbit hole and study patiently.

Comment: Yes, remember it, and you say that lacks clarity, are you saying that this new statement is true: "any object that moves in the a1,a2,a3 directions moves at the speed 1?"

Comment: Before going to this $S^3$ example with three extra coordinates I think you will have an easier life when you try to grasp fully what happens in that Lorentzian example I commented yesterday: 1) The $xy$-plane does not move, in particular not at the speed of light. 2) *Any* object that moves in the $z$-direction can do so only at the speed of light. A no brainer since the constraint $dt^2=dz^2$ leads to $\dot z=1\,.$ Now carry this insight over to your lovely 7-dimensional spacetime.

Comment: Now I see your point here and the lack of clarity in the original quote by me. Now everything is clear. Thank you!